# Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self

Tags: mac

I've been having some random crashes on my mac and I'm trying to look through each problematic  thing coming up in the console.log

One of the things that keeps popping up is:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[105]  (com.apple.ReportCrash) Falling back to default Mach exception handler. Could not find: com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
```

As it turns out I don't have this file *com.apple.ReportCrash.Self* on my computer.

I have found other forums, namely [this one](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=192563) which explains a fix to copy and paste this file from the root library to the user library, however my mac just simply doesn't have this file at all.

This problem has been suggested by many users to be responsible for window crashes and random shutdowns but I can't seem to find a solution to not having the file in the first place.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: Which version of MacOS?

Answer (score 2):

This what there is in `com.apple.ReportCrash.Self.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.ReportCrash.Self</string>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.ReportCrash.Self</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DrainMessagesOnCrash</key>
            <string>All</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/System/Library/CoreServices/ReportCrash</string>
    </array>
    <key>MachExceptionHandler</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```